# Git track how a commit got into a branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-enterprise

Is there a way to track how a commit got into a branch? I'm working with git and github enterprise.

A couple of days ago, I came across a situation where a commit appears to have gotten from a feature branch ("*f*") into our first staging branch ("*s*"), which is as expected (my colleagure merged a PR to do just that). We have a secondary staging branch before our master ("*t*"), and somehow the commit in question got into *t* without a pull request from *f*. I can only assume that somehow, contrary to our usual workflow, code got merged from *s* to *t*, probably through some other feature branch. I'd like to trace the path that the commit in question took.

I fired up `gitk` to try to figure it out, but the problem I have is that I find the network diagram inscrutable. Is there any way to track the path of this commit, either using some other tool than `gitk`, or can you educate me (or point me to a good resource) to understand gitk's diagram?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--ancestry-path` to simplify gitk diagram.

`$ gitk offending_commit..HEAD --ancestry-path`

This will show only commits that are descendents of the commit `offending_commit` and antecessors of the HEAD of current branch (you can use any two commits separated by `..`).

Comment: Thank you for this, I think I'll use this in future. It hasn't revealed the answer, but I think maybe if I can identify the first commit with my offending commit as an ancestor, I can figure this out with gitk.

Comment: OK, I did that, and it's still a mystery. Thank you anyway, though - this definitely seems like it should be the tool to solve this problem, and you've definitely upgraded my toolset with this knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

In your GitHub Enterprise site, navigate in your `t` branch to view an affected file. On that file, you'll see a `Blame` button. Click that and look at all the changes listed for a change that you know is specific to `s`.

You should be able to identify the commit, user id, timestamp, and comment of the effected area of that file which may help you determine how it got there.

For viewing networks, I like the view provided by [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (Free, Windows and Mac)

Comment: I know what the commit is and who committed it. I want to know how that commit got into the affected branch.